# Examples in which $m(X)=∞ $ and $L^p(X,B,m)⊂L^q(X,B,m)$ for some p,q with 1⩽p<q<∞?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I've found this theorem online:

Theorem: Let $(X,B,m)$ be a σ-finite measure space, where m is a non-negative measure. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

1. We have $L^p(X,B,m)⊃L^q(X,B,m)$ for some $p,q$ with $1⩽p<q<∞$.
2. $m(X)<∞$.

I read the proof, but I can't convince myself that these two conditions are equivalent. Could you , please, give me some examples in which $m(X)= ∞$ and $L^p(X,B,m)⊂ L^q(X,B,m)$ for some $p,q$ with $1⩽p<q<∞$?

Comment: Think about the $\ell^p$s, that is $\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb N, \mathcal P(\mathbb N), \#)$, where the sigma-algebra is just all the power set, and $\#$ is the counting measure.

Comment: Isn't that what is asked?

Comment: Notice that the statement you have written is that $m(X)=\infty$ is equivalent to the fact that, for all $1\le p<q<\infty$, $L^p(X,B,m)\nsupseteq L^q(X,B,m)$ (I must assume that here your $\supset$ means $\supseteq$, otherwise the statement fails for finite measures). Why do you have an interest in the specific intermediate occurrence where the reverse inequality holds instead of the negated inequality, and only in a specific instance?

Comment: The inclusion in the title is the opposite of the inclusion in the question - you should correct one of them

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little confusing; note that what you are asking has nothing to do with the theorem that you have seen; you should be asking for a measure space with infinite measure such that there exist $p<q\in [1,\infty)$ so that $L^q\not\subset L^p$.

Anyway, the theorem is true. I will try to demonstrate the proof in detail, using elementary functional analysis (the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem) to be more precise).

Let $1\leq p<q<\infty$ and $f\in L^q(X)$. Then we can apply Holder's inequality for the numbers $s=q/p>1$ and to its conjugate $t$ (i.e. $\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{t}=1)$, so
$$\|f\|_p^p=\int_X|f|^pd\mu=\int_X|f|^p\cdot1d\mu\leq\bigg(\int_X(|f|^p)^{q/p}d\mu\bigg)^\frac{p}{q}\cdot\bigg(\int_X1^td\mu\bigg)^{1/t}=\|f\|_q^p\cdot\mu(X)^{1/t}<\infty $$
So $$\|f\|_p\leq\mu(X)^{1/tp}\|f\|_q=\mu(X)^{\frac{q-p}{pq}}\|f\|_q\;\;\;(\star)$$ and this is true for all functions $f\in L^q$.

$(2)\implies(1)$ If $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $1\leq p<q<\infty$ and $f\in L^q$, then $\|f\|_p\leq\mu(X)^{\frac{q-p}{pq}}\|f\|_q<\infty$ by the above inequality, so $f\in L^p$ and the claim is proved.

$(1)\implies(2)$ Suppose that $L^q\subset L^p$ for all $1\leq p<q<\infty$. We can then define the identity operator $T_{q,p}:L^q(X)\to L^p(X)$ by $f\mapsto f$. Since both $L^p$ and $L^q$ are Banach spaces, we can apply the closed graph theorem to show that $T_{q,p}$ is a bounded operator: Indeed, if $(f_n)\subset L^q$ is a sequence with $\|f_n\|_q\to0$ and $\|f_n-g\|_p\to0$ for some $g\in L^p$, then we have that $f_n$ has a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging to $0$ almost everywhere. But $\|f_{n_k}-g\|_p\to0$, so $f_{n_k}$ has a subsequence covnerging to $g$ almost everywhere. But we already established that $f_{n_k}$ converges to $0$ almost everywhere, so $g=0$ almost everywhere, thus $\|f_{n}\|_p\to0$, i.e. $T_{q,p}f_n\to0$ in $L^p$, and by the closed graph theorem this shows that $T_{q,p}$ is bounded. In other words, $\|T_{q,p}\|<\infty$.

Recall the definition of operator norm: if $S:X\to Y$ is a linear operator, then $$\|S\|=\inf\{c\in[0,\infty): \|Sx\|\leq c\|x\| \text{ for all }x\in X\}=\sup_{x\in X,x\neq0}\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}\;\;(\star\star)$$
By $(\star)$ and the first equation of $(\star\star)$, $\|T_{q,p}\|\leq\mu(X)^{\frac{q-p}{pq}}$. On the other hand, if $f$ is the constant function $1$ on all $X$, then by the second equation of $(\star\star)$ we have that
$$\|T_{q,p}\|\geq\frac{\|f\|_p}{\|f\|_q}=\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}=\mu(X)^{\frac{q-p}{pq}} $$

Combining with the above, $$\|T_{q,p}\|=\mu(X)^{\frac{q-p}{pq}}$$
and since $\|T_{q,p}\|<\infty$ we have that $\mu(X)<\infty$.